backpropagation computation - Derivative of matrix with respect to another matrix
I am having some trouble computing gradients of the loss function of an MLP when the input is a minibatch of vectors.
Forward propagation

$\large \underbrace{Z^{[1]}}_{(n^{[1]},m)} = \underbrace{W^{[1]}}_{(n^{[1]},n^{[0]})} \underbrace{X}_{(n^{[0]},m)} + \underbrace{b^{[1]}}_{n^{(1)}} $
$\large \underbrace{A^{[1]}}_{(n^{[1]},m)} = f(Z^{[1]})$
$\large \underbrace{Z^{[2]}}_{(n^{[2]},m)} = \underbrace{W^{[2]}}_{(n^{[2]},n^{[1]})} \underbrace{A^{[1]}}_{(n^{[1]},m)} + \underbrace{b^{[2]}}_{n^{(2)}}$
$\large \underbrace{A^{[2]}}_{(n^{[2]},m)} = \sigma(Z^{[2]})$

where:

$\hat{y} = \large A^{[2]}$, in other words $\large A^{[2]}$ is the network output
$f$ is a Relu function (the code is provided)
$\sigma$ is a sigmoid function (the code is provided)
$m$ is the minibatch size (number of data samples in the minibatch)
$n^{[0]}$ is the number of neurons in the input layer (dimensionality of a data sample)
$n^{[1]}$ is the number of neurons in the hidden layer
$n^{[2]}$ is the number of neurons in the output layer

I use cross entropy as a loss function $\mathcal{L}$ and I want to compute
$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial W^{[2]}}$, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial W^{[1]}}$, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial b^{[2]}}$, $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial b^{[1]}}$
I didn't find any complete derivation online, what is the derivative of a matrix/vector w.r.t another matrix ? When and how is it defined ?
Thanks

Have you worked through the explanations in Chris Bishop’s book?

I just checked the backpropagation chapter and it does not really present what I am looking for. I would love if someone could help me with this example that I have been trying to understand for weeks. The wikipedia page on matrix calculus is also very difficult to read.

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\hh{\oslash}  \def\h{\odot}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\A{{\widehat A}}
\def\L{{\cal L}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\step#1{\op{step}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\r#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\r{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\b{\LR{#1}}}
\def\GLR#1{\g{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Define the all-ones vector $\o\in\R{m}$ and the following matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
Z_1 &= W_1X + b_1\o^T &\qiq dZ_1 = dW_1\,X + db_1\o^T \\
A_1 &= \max(Z_1,\,0) &\qiq dA_1 = \step{Z_1}\h dZ_1 \\
Z_2 &= W_2A_1 + b_2\o^T &\qiq dZ_2 = dW_2\,A_1 + W_2\,dA_1 + db_2\o^T \\
A_2 &= \sigma(Z_2) &\qiq dA_2 = (A_2 - A_2\h A_2)\h dZ_2 \\
}$$
where all functions are applied element-wise and $(\h/\hh)$ denote element-wise multiplication/division and the step() function is the Heaviside step function.
$\sf NB\!:\,$ I've turned the stage counter into a subscript and reserved superscripts for matrix operations such as transposition and inversion.
Finally, I'm using a colon $(:)$ to denote the Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B^*:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
\LR{C\h A}:B &= C:\LR{A\h B} \\
}$$
The following definitions saved me a lot of typing
$$\eqalign{
R &= \A\hh A_2 \\
Q &= R\h(A_2\h A_2-A_2) \;\equiv\; (\A\h A_2-\A) \\
S &= \step{Z_1}\h\LR{W_2^TQ} \\
\\
}$$

Starting with the loss function and working backwards
$$\eqalign{
\L &= -\A:\log(A_2) \\
d\L
 &= -\A:\LR{dA_2\hh A_2} \\
 &= -\LR{\A\hh A_2}:\r{dA_2} \\
 &= -R:\r{ \lR{(A_2 - A_2\h A_2)\h dZ_2} } \\
 &= \lR{R\h(A_2\h A_2-A_2)}:\g{dZ_2} \\
 &= Q:\GLR{dW_2\,A_1 + W_2\,dA_1 + db_2\o^T} \\
}$$
Pausing here, we can identify the following gradients
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\L}{W_2} &= QA_1^T, \q\q\q \grad{\L}{b_2} &= Q\o \\
}$$
Continuing with the remaining $dA_1$ component
$$\eqalign{
d\L &= \LR{W_2^TQ}:\r{dA_1} \\
 &= \LR{W_2^TQ}:\RLR{\step{Z_1}\h dZ_1} \\
 &= S:\g{dZ_1} \\
 &= S:\GLR{dW_1\,X + db_1\o^T} \\
}$$
At this point, we can identify our remaining gradients
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\L}{W_1} &= SX^T, \q\q\q \grad{\L}{b_1} &= S\o \\
\\
}$$

Notice that we didn't need to calculate any of those awkward matrix-by-matrix or matrix-by-vector gradients because we never explicitly used the Chain Rule. Instead, we back-substituted a sequence of differentials until we arrived at the desired variables.
The nice thing about a matrix differential is that it behaves almost exactly like the underlying matrix. In particular, it obeys all of the rules of Matrix Algebra and in terms of Matrix Calculus, differentials are related to gradients by
$$\boxed{
\\
\q dF = G:dX \qif G = \grad FX \q
\\
}$$
